# Making a button invisible by clicking another button in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, visibility, hidden

How can I make a button invisible by clicking another button in HTML?
I have written like below, but it doesn't work.

```
<input type="button" onclick="demoShow();" value="edit" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function demoShow()
    { document.getElementsByName('p2').style.visibility="hidden"; }
</script>
<input id="p2" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

Answer (score 14):

write this

To hide

```
{document.getElementById("p2").style.display="none";}
```

to show

```
{document.getElementById("p2").style.display="block";}
```

Answer (score 5):

**For Visible:**

```
document.getElementById("test").style.visibility="visible";
```

**For Invisible:**

```
document.getElementById("test").style.visibility="hidden";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `id` of the element to do the same.

```
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `getElementById` returns a single object for which you can specify the style.So, the above explanation is correct.
2. `getElementsByTagName` returns multiple objects(array of objects and properties) for which we cannot apply the style directly.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function demoShow() {   
document.getElementById("but1").style.display="none";

}



<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="demoShow()" id="but" />

<input type="button" value="hide" id="but1" />
```

Comment: if you want occupy some space in the sense apply "visibility:hidden", otherwise "display:none;"

Comment: I was just about to suggest that you explained the difference between the two lol

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery!

```
var demoShow = function(){
    $("#p2").hide();
}
```

But I would recommend you give an id to your button on which you want an action to happen.
For example:

```
<input type="button" id="p1" value="edit" />
<input type="button" id="p2" value="submit" name="submit" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("#p1").click(function(){
    $("#p2").hide();
});
</script>
```

To show it again you can simply write: `$("#p2").show();`

Answer (score 0):

To get an element by its ID, use this:

```
document.getElementById("p2")
```

Instead of:

```
document.getElementsByName("p2")
```

So the final product would be:

```
document.getElementsById("p2").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
<input type="button" onclick="demoShow()" value="edit" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function demoShow()
{document.getElementById("p2").style.visibility="hidden";}
</script>
<input id="p2" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#btn1" ).click(function() {
 $('#btn2').css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: This answer need more than a block of code.  For one thing, it depends on another third party library: jQuery.  A better answer describes what the code does and why the particular approach was chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="button" onclick="demoShow()" value="edit" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function demoShow()
{p2.style.visibility="hidden";}
</script>
<input id="p2" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

http://jsbin.com/gurolawu/1/

Answer (score 0):

I found problems with the elements being moved around using some of the above, so if you have objects next to each other that you want to just swap this worked best for me

```
document.getElementById('uncheckAll').hidden = false;
document.getElementById('checkAll').hidden = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did that way

```
<script>
            const AddMoreBtn = document.getElementById('add-more')
            AddMoreBtn.onclick = function(){
                if (document.getElementById('extraField').style.visibility == 'collapse'){
                    alert('Extra fields are not obligatory to be filled')             
                    document.getElementById('extraField').style.visibility='visible';
                } else{
                    document.getElementById('extraField').style.visibility='collapse';
                }
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).